# How does ship capture work on planet in starfield, and can I go back later to take it over?

Tags: starfield

I'm on my way to a mission where I need to scan some minerals on Akhila. I came across, and ... involuntarily retired the crew of an absolutely lovely Eclipse Stilleto. When I took off on it, to take over ownership, the mission I was on failed, which annoys me.

Can I go back to a spaceship parked on a planet I've killed everyone on to capture it later, and would it disappear if I didn't?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, no. They'll de-spawn eventually.

Spaceship landings are pretty random. Most of them aren't super special usually. I wouldn't stress over it. You'll easily find others from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get in the cockpit of the ship and sit down, and from there you will see it in your list of ships in your ship menu (bottom left section of the player menu) where you can mark it as your home ship without leaving planet to keep it, though doing that will move all of your cargo and the junk lying around inside of the ship into the new ship's cargo hold as well as despawn your other ship until you get to a shipyard to switch ships. Note that captured enemy ships that include contraband lying around on tables and the like, that contraband has a habit of disappearing when you go to orbit so it is best to pick it up and drop it off at one of your outposts until you can come back with a ship that has shielded cargo storage.

Comment: I dont believe loose junk moves ships, if you have a bunch of stuff on the floor loose, and change you home ship, the loose stuff gets despawned. So make sure you move any loose items to the cargo hold or captains locker before switching home ships.